# React Native app won't start when using applicationIdSuffix

Tags: android, react-native, adb, build.gradle

I am using `react-native-codepush@1.16.1-beta` and [part of the setup](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/#android-setup) includes specifying applicationIdSuffix.

I've set this up on a previous app in the past with no issues (React Native 0.37). I've encountered this error twice now with this project (React Native 0.40). The first time I rebuilt my entire project and it went away. It started happening again for no apparent reason so I cloned the last stable version of my project in a fresh directory, and got the same error.

The error occurs when using `react-native run-android`. The error happens after a successful build:

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.packagename/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.packagename/com.packagename.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

The error goes away if I remove `applicationIdSuffix ".debug"` from `app/build.gradle` and the app starts on my phone without issue.

My phone is a Nexus 6P with Android 7.0. I've only tried on a physical device since I don't have simulators set up.

I've triple checked everything against to my other project and I don't believe it's a configuration issue.

Comment: It should run after manually launching the app on phone. Happens to me as well.

Comment: Its familiar with the react team i believe: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/8950

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the link above, it's been discussed for a long time (over a year) on github, and there seems to be a few patches on their way, so my fix below may or may not work depending on the version of `react-native` you're using.

Here's how I've (temporarily) solved the issue. The problem is that `react-native-cli` tries to call `adb shell am start` with the wrong argument:

```
com.packagename/com.packagename.MainActivity
```

when it should be calling something like

```
com.packagename.debug/com.packagename.MainActivity
```

So until your version of `react-native` is fixed, you can use this command (as recommended in [this code-push PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/611):

```
cd android && ./gradlew installDebug && adb -s <DEVICE_ID> shell am start -n com.packageName.debug/com.packageName.MainActivity
```

It's not a perfect fix, but there's a patch on [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/13169/files) which does essentially the same thing (in relation to a couple of issues and pull requests [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/8950) & [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/12820)).

Comment: This solution has the advantage of not introducing a new build variant/flavor if none is needed. All devs can have a run configuration for debug and one for prod

Answer (score 40):

What Im using for React Native 0.60+ with multiple build configurations

In my `app/bundle.gradle` file I have the following configuration

```
productFlavors {
   dev {
       applicationId "com.my.app.development"
       dimension "standard"
   }
   production {
       applicationId "com.my.app"
       dimension "standard"
   }
}

buildTypes {
   release {
        // your release build values
   }
   debug {
       // your debug build values
       debuggable true
   }
}
```

For a **standard debug** build

`react-native run-android --variant devDebug --appIdSuffix \"development\"`

For a **Staging** build (dev variables, but built for release)

`react-native run-android --variant devRelease --appIdSuffix \"development\"`

For a **Release** build

`react-native run-android --variant productionRelease`

---

this worked for me on **react-native 0.50.3**

`react-native run-android --appIdSuffix "debug"`

Comment: You can see all the available params here - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js#L301

Comment: File location has changed: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cli/blob/master/packages/cli/src/logAndroid/logAndroid.js

Comment: ...and has changed again: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/commands.md#run-android

Answer (score 8):

If you have a custom applicationId (different from your Java package name), you have to specify it when running the `run-android` command

```
npx react-native run-android --appId com.custompackagename.debug
```

You will see the result at the end when react is starting the intent

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.custompackagename.debug/com.packagename.MainActivity
```

Comment: the definitive answer! appIdSuffix was not working, neither variant, only appId parameter solved the issue

Comment: Thank you, man! Finally fixed our builds are being broken by flavours.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a real solution either. Right now I am using a workaround where I don't use react-native run-... but use AndroidStudio directly.

I found a hint at http://sex-gril.com/project/45838.html which is saying that you have to add the package name to your defaultConfig in the build.gradle.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "Your App ID LIke in Manifest"
    }
}
```

But that did not work for me =/.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I use `applicationIdSuffix` to configure a custom environment.
From [the documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/commands.md#run-android), we have:

> --appId
>
> ```
> Specify an applicationId to launch after the build. If not specified, the
> package of AndroidManifest.xml will be used.
> ```
>
> --appIdSuffix
>
> ```
> Specify an applicationIdSuffix to run after the build.
> ```

So you should run your application like this

```
npx react-native run-android --appIdSuffix suffix
```

NOTE: Your suffix should not contain a dot prefix, it will be added automatically.